# How to inflate layout from extended activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have extended `BaseActivity` from `ActionBarActivity`, in which I set the activity's content. There's a `FrameLayout` in the layout file I use.

When I extend `BaseActivity` to use in e.g. `MainActivity`, I'd like `MainActivity` to inflate the `FrameLayout` with a custom layout file.

I couldn't come up with a solution. I always got errors. This is how far I came.

BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        FrameLayout mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        mFrame.addView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_nav_test, mFrame, true));
        return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    }
```

Thanks a lot for your help!
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems to be proper but add view inside frame layout in `onCreate` method instead.

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


FrameLayout mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        mFrame.addView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_nav_test, mFrame, true));
}
```

Comment: Where do I get the context from on onCreate?

Comment: Did work, when I changed the last line to `LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_nav_test, mFrame, true);`

Answer (score 0):

In this method :

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    FrameLayout mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    mFrame.addView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_nav_test, mFrame, true));
    return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```

You must return ur custom view. Try this. I hope it helps

```
return mFrame;
```